# Oracle column rows split in to multible columns

Tags: sql, oracle

select year, code, benchmark from table;

Result:Year,  code,       benchmark

```
    2017, MKPI00719, 1
    2017, MKPI00719, benchmark0001
    2017, MKPI00719, 2016
    2017, MKPI00719, 90
    2017, MKPI00743, 1
    2017, MKPI00743, benchmark34455
    2017, MKPI00743, 2013
    2017, MKPI00743, 900
```

I want to display below like this

```
 Year, code,        ben_value, desc,          b_year, kpi 
 2017, MKPI00719,   1,      benchmark0001,  2016,   90 
 2017, MKPI00743,  1,       benchmark87899, 2013,   900
```

This senario ben_value always one. that is the unique, grouping besed 
 on Year, code.

Please help me how to write my sql in oracle

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  Your re-arrangement of the data seems to rely on the ordering of the rows.  Do you have another column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: yes, got sequence no

Comment: Add that sequence no to your sample data - I don't understand how it works. What are the typical values in that sequence (for the rows you included)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence number, then I think the following solves your problem:

```
select year, code,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then benchmark end) as ben_value,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then benchmark end) as description,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then benchmark end) as b_year,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then benchmark end) as kpi
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, code order by sequence_no) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by year, code
```

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much